# Adding dropbox files over unsecure wi-fi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dropbox

So far I've always used private ISP connections (paid by myself) to access internet.
Now I'm  using a wi-fi connection that requires a login, but I'm certain it's shared by dozens of people, with the same login, and this connection is as well with a little shield on windows 8.1, which I know means nothing good.

This raised the very question I make above, If I add or change a file on my dropbox, will someone in this wi-fi be able steal the file, since it will have to "navigate" trough the wi-fi to reach the dropbox server?

Edit: I'd also like to know what I could do to make my connection on this wi-fi more secure, other than disable the network finding on windows.
Thank you

Comment: Insecure wireless connections are indeed insecure and hostile users can intercept your non-encrypted HTTP traffic.  If you are worried use a VON

Comment: what does changing a file on my dropbox folder has to do with http?

Comment: Because that is the protocol used by Dropbox for communication. Dropbox uses port 443, which is assigned to HTTPS.

Comment: My suggestion was supposed to say use a VPN.  Anyways as explained DropBox uses HTTPS to transfer files.

Comment: But https is different than http, http uses port 80. What if I change the port?

Answer (score 0):

No, even if you use insecure wifi, it would be infeasible for an attacker to steal your Dropbox data in transit. Aside from obviously not communicating in clear text and using SSL, Dropbox additionally uses certificate pinning to limit its exposure to potentially malicious or compromised CAs.

See: https://blogs.dropbox.com/dropbox/2014/06/weve-got-your-back/